# Which buildings benefit from engineers?

Tags: xcom-2

I keep building buildings that can't use engineers next to workshops, leaving some of the workshop's drones unused.  This is clearly not optimal.

So **which buildings benefit from engineers** *(and should thus be built next to workshops)*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taken from https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/44fwdf/what_facilities_can_staff_engineers/

Advanced Warfare Center - 1 slot - wounded soldiers need 50% less time to heal

Power Relay - 1 (+1 via Upgrade) slots - 5 Avenger Power each

Resistance Comms - 1 (+1 via Upgrade)  slots - 2 more resistance contacts possible on first slot, 4 on second slot

Proving Ground  - 1 slot - Half time required for PG projects

Psi Lab  - 1 slot - Half time for psi training

Defense Matrix  - 1 slot - Increases turrets' stats during Base Defense

Workshop provides 1+1(after upgrade) Engineer slots, each Engineer in there provides 2 GREMLINS, which count as an Engineer, so basically you can turn 2 Engineers into 4.
An easy way to use a workshop to it's full potential is to place the Comms and Power relay next to it, allowing you to staff both of these completely with two engineers. This would also eliminate the need to place the workshop in a central position (though, this will of course increase your flexibility).

Building two workshops doesn't seem to be possible, I finshed one and don't have the option to build another on the spot next to it.

Comment: It seems building two workshops is not possible, period.

Comment: Psi lab is expandable to 2 slots.

Comment: @Muz 2 slots for soldiers to train, only one for an engineer, which is what is asked here.

Comment: You point out that the Comms and Power Relay can take 2 engineers each, and so they make workshop placement more flexible. There's another advantage to putting these near the workshop: these are two rooms that will probably be staffed most consistently, while other rooms which might only need to be staffed occasionally can be placed anywhere and staffed by human engineers as needed. And of course, these are two facilities you need to build pretty early on, so they let you take advantage of a workshop early on, even when you're still severely limited as to building locations.

Comment: It might also be useful to have a list of the facilities that never need engineers, if only because that list is shorter: I think it's just the Lab, Guerilla Tactics School, and Shadow Chamber. Just remember to avoid putting those near your workshop and you'll be fine!

Comment: Would be nice to update the answer for the expansion pack if someone knows