# How do levels affect engineers and scientists?

Tags: xcom-2

The command to add scientists and engineers to your Avenger is as follows (roughly):

- `giveScientist [NUM_LVL]`
- `giveEngineer [NUM_LVL]`

What I'm curious about is what the level modifier does to scientists and engineers. I've tried low and high stats, like adding a level 9001 engineer and a level 100 scientists, and I still can't figure out if there's a cap on abilities, a level cap for engineers or scientists, and what the level affects.

Since engineers can actually affect a lot of different facilities, as mentioned [in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255072/which-buildings-benefit-from-engineers), how do levels affect engineers and scientists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They don't, at least not anymore.

Essentially at some point, there was a leveling system where Engineers and Scientists had a level from 1 to 10, and gave a certain number of "points". Certain research or proving grounds projects required a certain number of points.

For example, Sectoid Autopsy required 10 Science Points.

None of that leveling is actually used anymore. I mean, the code is all still there, but the way the values are set means that every Engineer and Scientist gives 5 points. Tygan and Shen count, so to reach the 10 Points for Sectoid Autopsy, you need 1 additional scientist.

Comment: That's interesting, but when I tried adding high level scientists it greatly affected the bonuses you got from placing them in certain rooms. For example, my level 4000 engineer added +27 contacts in my communications relay room, and another high level engineer added +22 staffing gremlins

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you can get High Level engineers in the game, unless I'm mistaken and you can get them from missions. It does seem that they can't level up though.

Comment: Engineers still seem to make a difference, Scientists no longer seem to (Research Speed % increase seems to be`1/Number Of Scientists`, so 50, 33, 25, 20,...)

Comment: Using a level 10 engineer in a workshop provides many extra gremlin drones.